# Implementing Popback in constant time in a singly linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I wanted to know if it was possible(*It should be as std::list seems to do it*) to implement a PopBack() operation on a singly linked list  in constant time and how?

I am assuming that we store head and tail pointers. In such a case, PushBack(), PushFront(), PopFront() can be easily implemented in constant time. But can't think of the way to implement PopBack() with the same running time.

Comment: `std::list` is doubly linked. `std::forward_list`, which is singly linked, does not have a `pop_back` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not implement `pop_back` for a single linked list in a constant time. To do this you need to know the previous element before the last that is the last element shall contain a reference to the previous element. If so then you will have a double linked list.

You can inplement `push_back` in a constant time. One of my proposals for C++ Standard was to introduce `std::x_forward_list` that will support `push_back` member function. In this case you will be able to use such a single linked list to simulate a queue.

Comment: Aaah....ofcourse and that must be the case with std::list..it looks like a dumb question now...I should sleep, its 3:00 am in India here!

Comment: If this operation would be implemented then the container would have bidirectional iterator. But a single linked list can not have a bidirectional iterator.